# Get first N <tr> that has <td> as child using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<table>` that has rows, first row is of-course header and other 10 non header rows. I want to get top 3 non-header rows (simply that has `td` child not `th`)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> Header 1 </th>
        <th> Header 2 </th>
        <th> Header 3 </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Row 1 Cell 1 </td>
        <td> Row 1 Cell 2 </td>
        <td> Row 1 Cell 3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Row 2 Cell 1 </td>
        <td> Row 2 Cell 2 </td>
        <td> Row 2 Cell 3 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am using JQuery

```
var sideNotification = jq(jq.parseXML(response.d))
    .find('tr').has("td")
    .each(function (index) {
        if (index < 3) {
            return {
                leadNo: $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(),
                product: $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text(),
                status: $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text()
            }
        }
    });
console.log(sideNotification.length);
```

But it still return 10 as count. How to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combination of [:has](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [:lt](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selectors.

```
$('tr:has(td):lt(3)').css('color', 'red');
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ^^               tr       -->  Select all tr elements
     ^^^^^^^        :has(td) -->  Select all tr elements having `td` as descendent
             ^^^^^  :lt(3)   -->  Get first three elements
```

```js
$('tr:has(td):lt(3)').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2 Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 Cell 2</td>
    <td>Row 2 Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2 Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 Cell 2</td>
    <td>Row 2 Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2 Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 Cell 2</td>
    <td>Row 2 Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect, oversimplified. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Imad Welcome! Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$("tr:lt(4)").filter(function () {
   return $(this).find("td").length > 0;
})
```

1. `:lt(4)` will get all the tr elements whose index is less than 4.
2. Then you can eliminate the header by checking the count of `td` in each tr.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/143/)

Comment: This will work if the first 4 `tr` elements don't have `td` in it. Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/y544g7qx/)

Comment: bro, your code too has the same meaning," it wont work if the first 4 tr elements don't have td in it"

Comment: Dear Anoop, I did test my code before adding the above comment. Please check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/y544g7qx/2/), containing both of our code.

Comment: You're first selecting the first four `tr`'s and then filtering from them, whereas I'm first filtering `tr`s and then selecting first 3 from them. Hope that's clear.